# App crashes on emulator while launching but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator

While launching the application on emulator the following exception is occurred. But running on device it is working fine. Please help to get rid of the issue.
have been facing the issue around five days. cannot get any proper solution.

```
2018-10-13 07:45:15.423 1742-1756/system_process E/ActivityManager: Activity Manager Crash. UID:1000 PID:1742 TRANS:5
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:224)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.<init>(LoadedApk.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:2043)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1998)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1970)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2054)
            at com.android.server.AttributeCache.get(AttributeCache.java:135)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.<init>(ActivityRecord.java:903)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:804)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:528)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1057)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:473)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4841)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4817)
            at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:146)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3114)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
    2018-10-13 07:45:15.424 9564-9564/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


        --------- beginning of crash
    2018-10-13 07:45:15.425 9564-9564/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher, PID: 9564
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1948)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1865)
            at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1660)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4574)
            at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:1394)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4889)
            at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivitySafely(SourceFile:2000)
            at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startAppShortcutOrInfoActivity(SourceFile:1850)
            at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.onClick(SourceFile:1703)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6579)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6556)
            at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:777)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25660)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
         Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
            at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:224)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.<init>(LoadedApk.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:2043)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1998)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1970)
```

Comment: From this Error log it's not possible to help you so much because it hasn't any reference to your classes. I think the problem is in the Main class that is launched at the beginning. Could you write the Manifest and the Main class?

Comment: I have the same problem, with Emulator targeting `API Level P`, I think it's emulator problem